# Checkstyle - One Declaration per line aligned to a block

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

i'm trying to configure Eclipse Checkstyle but I can't find the option for two things:

in methods i want for each declaration a new line:

```
public int calc (int x, 
                 int y,
                 int z) {
}
```

and NOT:

```
public int calc (int x, int y, int z) {
}
```

and declarations should be wrapped like this

```
private var                a;
private int []             b = null;
private ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
```

and NOT:

```
private var a;
private int [] b = null;
private ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
```

I already tried the "MultipleVariableDeclarations" and the OneStatementPerLine but those work only inside of methods not for the Parameters of a method.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: just curious, why instead of following the conventions widely used in the industry you're trying to invent your own style (which looks weird)?

Comment: I think the OP is attemtpting to use a C/C++ style. Maybe this is because part of the codebase is in one of those languages already.

Comment: actually i have all of this from a code convention which recommends only  one declaration or statement per line to improve readability.

Comment: Are you talking about Checkstyle (http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/), or the code-formatter built-in in eclipse?

Comment: I'm talking about Checkstyle. with the code-formatter built-in in eclipse i already found the options, but i want a warning to appear not only to correct it with shift + ctr + F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there are build-in Checkstyle rules for that. The build-in rules aim to maintain a style that is common and established. Like @yegor256 already said, yours isn't. You can browse [this site](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/availablechecks.html) for any checks that match your requirement. I couldn't find any. As a last option you can always [write your own check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html).

A tip for the code formatter: Go to `Window`->`Preferences` and filer for `Save Actions`. There you can define that your code should always be formatted on save. Maybe you don't need a tool like Checkstyle to warn you about unformatted code then.

Answer (score 0):

There is no build-in Checkstyle rules for that. However, for method arguments/parameters alignment you can use lib with additional checks for checkstyle - [check-tfij-style](https://github.com/tfij/check-tfij-style).

**1. Add lib to your `maven-checkstyle-plugin` (works with Gradle too) as a dependency, e.g.:**

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <configLocation>src/main/resources/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
        <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
        <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>validate</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.tfij</groupId>
            <artifactId>check-tfij-style</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

**2. Configure your checkstyle checks, e.g.:**

```xml
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="MethodParameterAlignment"/>
    <module name="MethodParameterLinesCheck">
      <property name="allowSingleLine" value="false"/>
    </module>
  </module>
```

**Notice**

The lib contains more useful checks. Read the readme file for more details - [check-tfij-style](https://github.com/tfij/check-tfij-style).